# How do we keep looping music keep going in the other pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to loop my music background and keep it going even if I move to my other pages, how can I achieve that? now the code below I wrote its works when I click pause and start button but I want a simpler way to keep it loop in other pages without clicking the start button.

Comment: so call x.Play() in window.load function. After page load it start. You can delay it with setTimeout function.

Comment: Why though? If it's a single page app its possible but generally speaking I don't think it's a good idea. If it's not a SPA I'd say it's impossible without some breakage and a bad user experience.

Comment: @Phix am working on a game project so just to give game vibe am adding looping music to other pages while playing, like whenever moving to a different page it should keep looping

Comment: @daremachine can u give me the code for it? the way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want?

```
<script>
window.onload = function(e) {
    var x=document.getElementById("Audi");
    x.play();
};
</script>
```

Or you can delay with wrapper `setTimeout`

```
<script>
window.onload = function(e) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        var x=document.getElementById("Audi");
        x.play();
    }, 200);
};
</script>
```

Comment: is it gonna loop if I move to the next page like the music gonna keep running?